# Issues while accessing system files with su in Chinese make Tablet. (Android 4.0.3)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, root-access

I have a cheap chinese tablet with Android 4.0.3.

I'm a linux enthusiast and of course I wanna explore the Android capabilities deeper.(I own Nokia N900 and without rooting its nothing).

So my tablet is WM8850.

The interesting is that I can browse in the `/`, but when I ask for **root 
privileges**  **`su`** , it says that:

I'm not allowed to access prompt with `su priviledges`.

`UID XXXX not allowed to  su`.

So do I need to do the all rooting process or I just have to install the super user package?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get root privilege. Merely installing Super User won't do anything.
EDIT: 
SuperUser must be placed in /system (made a "system app") in order to work, which is not done by "merely installing it", and cannot be done without aquiring root privileges

Comment: Funny thing though that `su` seems to be present. Maybe you should point out why "merely installing SuperUser won't do anything"? IMHO the problem is, *SuperUser* must be placed in `/system` (made a "system app") in order to work, which is not done by "merely installing it", and cannot be done without aquiring root privileges.

Comment: Feel free to integrate it with your answer :)

Comment: Yes, I did the same.